# What does [ ] and [0] mean in php with arrays?

Tags: php

I'm using wordpress and I"m grabbing a custom taxonomy and the code I'm using is

```
$terms = get_the_terms($HeroID, 'hero-universe' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $franchise_slug[] = $term->slug; // this grabs the hyphenated slug
    $franchise_name[] = $term->name; // this grabs the actual name
}
```

Than to display the custom taxonomy I use

```
<?php echo $franchise_name[0]; ?>
```

I was wondering what the brackets are for and why do I use the number 0? It seems that if I take the brackets away from both the  $franchise_name[] and $franchise_slug[] that it works properly too so what is the reason for them?

Thank you.

Comment: `[]` is append a new entry (no matter its type). `[0]` means address the first entry (index) of the array (counting starts from 0).

Comment: Have you read the doc on php.net? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
It should probably answer all your questions.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? Specifically code example #4 and the chapter "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax".

Comment: How appropriate that this shows in the sidebar at the moment: [Where are the non-trivial PHP-questions lately?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252443/476)

Answer (score 0):

`[]`  and `[0]` are used with arrays of values...

```
$arr = array();

// add "blah" at the end of my array
$arr[] = "bla";
// add "niania" at the end of my array
$arr[] = "niania";

// output the first value of my array :
echo $arr[0]; // blah
// output the second value of my array :
echo $arr[1]; // niania
```

If you use some foreach structure and do not know what is an array, you gonna have a bad time...

[Where are the non-trivial PHP-questions lately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252443/where-are-the-non-trivial-php-questions-lately?cb=1) ...

A little search on Google should have give you the answer.

Comment: If you downvote an answer you are supposed to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a collection of values. in PHP you can either assign a value to a variable:

`$value = 1;`

or add a bunch of similar values into an array:

`$programming_languages = ['PHP', 'C++', 'Ruby'];`

To print our value to the screen does vary, since our `$value` only holds 1 actual value we can just echo it out to the screen:

`echo $value; // prints 1`

but since our `$programming_languages` holds multiple values we would need to print it differently. We can access each value using indexes which start at 0:

`echo $programming_languages; // echos Array()`

`echo $programming_languages[0]; // echos 'PHP'`

`echo $programming_languages[1]; // echos 'C++'`

`$franchise_slug[] = $term->slug` Pushes a value into the end of an array, so `$franchise_slug` is your array, and you're looping through all your terms adding every slug into the end of this array. So using our examples above, we can access the first slug by using the index of 0.